# Parsing Tabbed Numbers on a Line

Tags: python

I have a text file with a bunch of lines of series of numbers, resembling this format:

```
1   80,982  163,8164    170,2620    145,648 200,8021    173,2069    92,647  26,4122 140,546 11,1913 160,6461    27,7905 40,9047 150,2183    61,9146 159,7420    198,1724    114,508 104,6647    30,4612 99,2367 138,7896    169,8700    49,2437 125,2909    117,2597    55,6399
```

I'd like to create a nested dictionary that maps the first number in the sets of two numbers to the second, and have all of that mapped to the line number. So for the first few entries in this example (line 1), it would look like this:

```
{1: {80: 982}, {163: 8164}, {170: 2620}}
```

I'm not sure how to achieve this with my limited text parsing  abilities. Would I use the split method using tabs and commas as delimiters?

Comment: this is not a valid dictionary: `{1: {80: 982}, {163: 8164}, {170: 2620}}`, it's supposed to be key:value pair, for all elements, not only for the first one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [32]: line = '1   80,982  163,8164    170,2620    145,648 200,8021    173,2069    92,647  26,4122 140,546 11,1913 160,6461    27,7905 40,9047 150,2183    61,9146 159,7420    198,1724    114,508 104,6647    30,4612 99,2367 138,7896    169,8700    49,2437 125,2909    117,2597    55,6399'

In [33]: tok = line.split()

In [34]: {int(tok[0]): dict(map(int, t.split(',')) for t in tok[1:])}
Out[34]: 
{1: {11: 1913,
  26: 4122,
  27: 7905,
  30: 4612,
  40: 9047,
  49: 2437,
  55: 6399,
  61: 9146,
  ...
```

Here:

- `int(tok[0])` is the line number;
- `(... for t in tok[1:])` iterates over the pairs of numbers, assigning each pair to `t` as a string;
- `t.split(',')` splits each pair into a 2-tuple of strings;
- `map(int, ...)` converts each 2-tuple of strings into a 2-tuple of ints;
- `(map(int, t.split(',')) for t in tok[1:])` is a generator expression that yields the 2-tuples of ints one by one;
- finally, `dict(...)` converts the output of the generator into a dictionary.

If you find any of this confusing, I'd recommend experimenting with the code in an interactive shell, peeling the levels of complexity off one by one.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on in this code? I can't wrap my head around it; have never seen the In/Out structure  before.

Comment: @user1427661 The In/Out structure is simply a different python shell (ipython). The stuff after the 'In's are what NPE typed in (similar to >>> in the standard shell) and the stuff after the 'Out' is the output of each line if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

the internal part can be easily converted with:

```
dict([(int(i),int(j)) for (i,j) in [k.split(',') for k in a.split()[1:]]])
```

for

```
a = '1   80,982  163,8164    170,2620    145,648 200,8021    173,2069'
```

the output will be

```
{163: 8164, 200: 8021, 170: 2620, 173: 2069, 80: 982, 145: 648}
```

not sure about the first element (see the comment above)